# Adding property to element programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Alright, so my question is how I can add a prop to a component programmatically, here is my case, I have this in my `render()` for example:

```
              <TextField
                name="password"
                variant="outlined"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                className={classNames(styles.signUpInputField, styles.override)}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onBlur={this.validate}
              ></TextField>
```

You can see this goes into a validate function, it's a lengthy one so I'll just give you an example and not my actual validate function:

```
  validateEmail = event => {
    if (event.target.name !== "email") {
         ///Set HelperText and error props here
    } 
  };
```

What I want to happen is to modify props on my `<TextField>`, namely setting `error= true` and `helperText= "some error here"`, How can I do this inside my function?

EDIT: I would need to avoid using states, as there are multiple fields that would need to be assigned exclusively, and multiple states for each is not a clean approach imo.

Comment: I did this https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-fire-uhs04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a state to your component.

For multiple inputs, i implement this 
[this](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-platform-rcecm)

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
state = {
   error: false,
   helperText: '',
}

validateEmail = event => {
    if (event.target.name !== "email") {
         ///Set HelperText and error props here
         this.setState({error: true, helperText: "some error here"})
    } 
  };

render (
   <TextField
      name="password" 
      variant="outlined"
      label="Password"
      type="password"
      className={classNames(styles.signUpInputField, styles.override)}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onBlur={this.validate}
      error={this.state.error}
   />
   {this.state.helperText}
);
}
```

Comment: I used that approach on a previous page, but on this page I have about 8 fields, each would need to have their error / helpertext set exclusively, so making 8 states doesn't sound like a good approach, is there no way to manipulate directly without states?

Comment: There is a lot of approach but it depend on what you need

Comment: What I need is to be able to manipulate that value of "error" on a specific `TextField`, referencing it through `event.target` or such, not through states

Comment: When do you call your validate function ?  When submit or on change

Comment: I call it onBlur, that happens when you focus out of it so I only check once.

Comment: Take a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-fire-uhs04

Answer (score 3):

You have to add using `state` instead of `props`.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
  state = {
   error: false,
   helperText: '',
 }
}

validateEmail = event => {
    if (event.target.name !== "email") {
         ///Set HelperText and error state here
         this.setState({error: true, helperText: "some error here"})
    }
  };

render (
   ...

   <TextField
      name="password" 
      variant="outlined"
      label="Password"
      type="password"
      className={classNames(styles.signUpInputField, styles.override)}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onBlur={this.validate}
      error={this.state.error} // add this new line
   />
   <span>{this.state.helperText}</span>

   ....
);
}
```

Comment: I specifically want to avoid the state approach as I have multiple fields and wouldn't want to make a state for each.

Answer (score 0):

To add properties programmatically you can use JSX spread syntax `{...props}`:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
state = {
   error: false,
   helperText: '',
   additionalProps: {}
}

validateEmail = event => {
    if (event.target.name !== "email") {
         ///Set HelperText and error props here
         this.setState({
         additionalProps: {error: true, helperText: "some error here"}
         })
    } 
  };

render (
   <TextField
      {...this.state.additionalProps}
      name="password" 
      variant="outlined"
      label="Password"
      type="password"
      className={classNames(styles.signUpInputField, styles.override)}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onBlur={this.validate}
      error={this.state.error}
   />
   {this.state.helperText}
);
}
```

Comment: I specifically want to avoid the state approach as I have multiple fields and wouldn't want to make a state for each.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in one state only. Just use the `onChange()` method to change the state according to the field. If suppose the error pops on the email field, in the `onChange()` method of the email field check for the error and if error occurs, change the state (error and helpertext) accordingly. And update the field where the error will show, after updating the state.

Comment: If I have multiple fields having different helperText values, it wouldn't work, the helper text would be appearing on every single one because the state can only have one value. same for error.

Comment: A field being assigned a prop as a state will update automatically as the state updates, you cant control that.

Comment: No state can change on every edit you make on the text field.